# GWT app crashes in run-time when RequestContext interface is used in client code

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea, uibinder, requestfactory

I've been fighting with this issue for 3 days and I guess StackOverflow is my last resort. I ran out of ideas why it doesn't work :( I'm using GWT 2.4.0 and JDK 1.6.

I was going through **[this tutorial](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html)** and got stuck with crashing GWT app. The app crashes if I mention com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.RequestContext interface in my client code. I'm not even using it. I just have unused method that takes RequestContext as parameter. I tried referencing RequestFactory - same exception. So I suspect I'm missing something related to RequestFactory package. I added -logLevel DEBUG to GWT compiler and here is what I have:

```
DEBUG: Rebinding com.vsezavtra.courierApp.client.ManagerShell.ManagerShellUiBinder. 
  DEBUG: Checking rule <generate-with class='com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.gwt.rebind.RequestFactoryGenerator'/>. 
    ERROR: Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/work/externals/gwt/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/shared/Receiver.java'. 
    ERROR: Unable to find type 'com.vsezavtra.courierApp.client.ManagerShell.ManagerShellUiBinder'. 
      ERROR: Line 26: The import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved. 
      ERROR: Line 79: ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved to a type. 
      ERROR: Line 81: ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved to a type. 
      ERROR: Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable. 
      ERROR: Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly. 
ERROR: Deferred binding failed for 'com.vsezavtra.courierApp.client.ManagerShell.ManagerShellUiBinder'; expect subsequent failures. 
ERROR: Unable to load module entry point class com.vsezavtra.courierApp.client.courierApp (see associated exception for details). java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'com.vsezavtra.courierApp.client.ManagerShell$ManagerShellUiBinder' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:97)
    at com.vsezavtra.courierApp.client.ManagerShell.<clinit>(ManagerShell.java:15)
    at com.vsezavtra.courierApp.client.courierApp.onModuleLoad(courierApp.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebind(ModuleSpace.java:595)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:455)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:49)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:97)
    at com.vsezavtra.courierApp.client.ManagerShell.<clinit>(ManagerShell.java:15)
    at com.vsezavtra.courierApp.client.courierApp.onModuleLoad(courierApp.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
ERROR: Failed to load module 'courierApp' from user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1' at localhost:10695.
```

Full log is **[here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=46aiBLME)**. My application is very small. Here is my GWT XML file

```
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/releases/2.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to="courierApp">
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
    <inherits name="com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.RequestFactory"/>

    <source path="client"/>

    <entry-point class='com.vsezavtra.courierApp.client.courierApp'/>
</module>
```

Main entry-point class:

```
package com.vsezavtra.courierApp.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootLayoutPanel;

public class courierApp implements EntryPoint
{
    public void onModuleLoad()
    {
        RootLayoutPanel.get().add(new ManagerShell());
    }
}
```

Bindable UI class

```
package com.vsezavtra.courierApp.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiBinder;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;
import com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.RequestContext;

public class ManagerShell extends Composite
{
    interface ManagerShellUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, ManagerShell>
    {
    }

    private static ManagerShellUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(ManagerShellUiBinder.class);

    public ManagerShell()
    {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }
    // if I remove this method everything works :(
    public void SetTest(RequestContext test) {}
}
```

and corresponding XML file

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder' xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
    <g:VerticalPanel>
        <g:HTMLPanel>
            Test!
        </g:HTMLPanel>
        <g:HTMLPanel>
            Test2!
        </g:HTMLPanel>
    </g:VerticalPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

and finally my web.xml file has only root "web-app" element because I have no server-side part (yet).

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 10.5.2 to debug the app.

Please let me know if you have any additional question. I really don't know what else I can do :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you are missing a javax.validation implementation that RequestFactory is dependent on:

> ERROR: Line 81: ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved to a type.

In the tutorial for [RequestFactory](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html#wiring) in the Wiring section **hibernate-validator** is recommended as well as several other dependencies:

> ```
> * requestfactory-server.jar
> * javax/validation/validator-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
> * A JSR 303 Validator of your choice, such as hibernate-validator
> ```

Comment: Doh, it was missing **validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar**. I would never think ! Thanks a lot for pointing me to right direction, Terrell.